# New packages not showing up in unstaged changes - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gitlab

I apologize in advance if this is a patently obvious question, but my group and I are trying to add new packages to a project. We are all working in eclipse, and have added packages to the project before. We are working inside our own packages, and all pushing to the master branch.

the problem is this:
whenever we make a change inside a current package, we see it pop up in the unstaged changes bar in the Git staging box. But when we make a new package, save, and then go to the git staging, nothing new appears in the unstaged changes box.

Any insight is appreciated, thank you.

--EDIT--

I found a way of working around this, but it is not elegant. I right clicked, compare with... > INDEX then I copied all of the code from the LH side to the RH side, saved,and closed the view. Then I could commit the changes, and the future changes were all tracked. 
I feel as though there should be a more direct way of just automatically tracking new classes. If anyone can provide a better solution, then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you make a new class in that package, you've only just created a directory on disk--an *empty* directory at that. You can't stage empty directories because `git` doesn't track empty directories.

Comment: Hi Nitind: yes, we have classes inside of it. After a bit of tinkering we figured that out. Perhaps I should have mentioned that. I suspect that it might be a problem which is too difficult to answer over the internet.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I actually noticed late last night, that the new packages do not have the little yellow cylinder on the bottom right of their icon. I suspect that means that they are not synchronized with the git repository. I would have no clue as to how to amend this. perhaps this information is of use?